# How to write a VB task script that checks when a file is no longer being used?

Tags: windows, events, vbscript, triggers

Is there an event that triggers when a particular file, which was being used by some process, is no longer being used? If there is no event, is there another way to detect this in a way that can trigger a task?

Comment: Not using VBScript there's not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```vbs
Dim file
Dim app

file = "C:\Test\file.xlsx"
app = "notepad.exe"
On Error Resume Next
Do
    CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").MoveFile file, file
    If Err <> 70 Then Exit Do ' 70 - Access denied
    Err.Clear
    WScript.Sleep 1
Loop
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run app
```

Once being launched the script waits until the `file` is free, then runs the `app` and exits.